# How to profile message activity?

Tags: ros, messages, ros-kinetic, topics

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Are there any tools for profiling or collecting statistics on the types of message activity per node?

I'm trying to troubleshoot some nodes consuming excessive amounts of CPU, and to help diagnose the problem, I'd like to get a histogram of the types of messages they publish over a given time range.

e.g. If I find something like:

```
topic                     messages/min
/mynode/encoders          23
/mynode/button            1
/mynode/imu               239423847887
/mynode/gps               56
```

then I'll immediately know it's publish rate for IMU messages is too high.

Obviously, I could do this manually by checking every single topic, but it's be nice to have a tool to automate this, and I don't want to reinvent the wheel.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/245636/how-to-profile-message-activity?/) by [Cerin](https://answers.ros.org/users/2186/cerin/) on ROS Answers with karma: 940 on 2016-10-13

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Since *ROS Indigo* there is builtin support for topic statistics in ROS. Based on [the documentation](http://wiki.ros.org/Topics#Topic_statistics), these are the metrics that are collected:

- Period of messages by all publishers (average, maximum, standard deviation)
- Age of messages, based on header timestamp (average, maximum, standard deviation)
- Number of dropped messages
- Traffic volume (Bytes)

To enable this feature, the `/enable_statistics` parameter needs to be set to `true`.

There are some tools that enable higher level analysis, visualisation and diagnostics based on topic statistics:

- [rqt_graph](http://wiki.ros.org/rqt_graph#Topic_statistics) (Visualisation of topic statistics)
- [rosprofiler](http://wiki.ros.org/rosprofiler) (Profiler and Visualisation based on topic statistics)
- [arni](http://wiki.ros.org/arni) (Visualisation and Fault Detection/Mitigation based on topic statistics and a custom process and host level monitor)

There is also a tool called [Drums](http://drums-project.github.io/) that collects fine-grained statistics about hosts, processes and network sockets that are part of a running ROS computation graph independent of the builtin data from ROS topic statistics. (*Disclaimer:* I am the author of *Drums* and the documentation is far from perfect at the moment).

---

Originally posted by [Mani](https://answers.ros.org/users/1858/mani/) with karma: 1704 on 2016-10-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Cerin](https://answers.ros.org/users/2186/cerin/) on 2016-10-13**:
When you say set "/enable_statistics" to true, on which node? All of them?

**Comment by [Thomas D](https://answers.ros.org/users/304/thomas-d/) on 2016-10-13**:
The [documentation](http://wiki.ros.org/Topics#Topic_statistics) link explains how to set the `/enable_statistics` parameter. It can also be done in a launch file similar to `/use_sim_time`.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you create a bag file then do `rosbag info` it will show you how many messages occur on each topic.

---

Originally posted by [Thomas D](https://answers.ros.org/users/304/thomas-d/) with karma: 4347 on 2016-10-13

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1